# Swift keyboard avoiding view is not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

In the GIF above, the `loginMenu` is supposed to be a keyboard avoiding view. It never gets covered by the keyboard. When start to edit either of those text fields, `loginMenu` does get "pushed up", however, upon editing, `loginMenu` goes back to its original location. What is wrong here? This is my code:

```
import UIKit;

class LoginScreenViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var loginMenu: UIView!;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)),
            name: .UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame,
            object: nil
        );
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self);
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillChange(notification: Notification) {
        let keyboardHeight = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue.height;
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.loginMenu.frame.origin.y = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - keyboardHeight - self.loginMenu.frame.height;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is solution, Create bottom layout constraint reference of `loginMenu` view

```
@IBOutlet weak var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var loginMenu: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @objc func handleKeyboardNotification(_ notification: Notification) {

    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {

        let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).cgRectValue

        let isKeyboardShowing = notification.name == NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow

        bottomConstraint?.constant = isKeyboardShowing ? -keyboardFrame!.height : 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
}
```

[Demo Example](https://github.com/paresh1994/KeyboardEx)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use keyboard will change (also you'll get incorrect behavior when dictation is chosen). Rather use willShow and then Will disappear to move your views/Fields.

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillDisappear(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

I also placed an observer on UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChange for such problems with dictation and Google Keyboard.

An alternative is to use IQKeyboardManagerSwift, unless you have a great reason for your custom version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` for remove this problam,

for exammple

```
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.loginMenu.frame.origin.y = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - keyboardHeight - self.loginMenu.frame.height;
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            });
```

Heare work of self.view.layoutIfNeeded() :-

Essentially calling the self.view.layoutIfNeeded() will force the layout of self.view and its subviews if some change set setNeedsLayout for self.view.

setNeedsLayout is used to set a flag that whenever layoutIfNeeded() is called, layoutSubviews will then be called. It is what determines the "if needed" aspect of the call.

If you make a change to UIView which causes it to setNeedsLayout but layoutIfNeeded() is not called (therefore layoutSubviews is not called) it will not update and therefore could cause issues with your animation. If you call it before hand it will ensure that if there was a change that needed your layout to be updated then it will apply it to your view and all of its subviews before animating.

And of course, when animating you are making changes which need to be updated.